# Исключить пустые значения массива из цикл

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

В настоящий момент у меня есть цикл, в рамках которого я собираю массив в цикле (значений из БД), что бы в дальнейшем отправить только те значения, которые были выбраны.
Пример кода:

```
$result = $mysql->getAll("SELECT `id`, `realname`, `mail` FROM dbase WHERE `system` = 1");
$arrayid= explode(',', $_POST['temp_id']);
$array = [];
foreach ($result as $info) {
    $text = '';
    $mail= '';
    if (in_array($info['id'], $arrayid)) {
        $text = $info['realname'];
        $mail= $info['mail'];
    }
    $array[] = ['name' => $text, 'mail' => $mail];
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что есть "пустые значения"? Пустая строка? null? Почему их нельзя исключить на этапе выборки из БД? Каков input, каков текущий output? Пример необходимого output'а?  Вроде не сложно это всё описать, но почему-то все ленятся это делать

Comment: вот получили вы список в запросе, если их какое-то адекватное количество, то проверив что это действительно числа, надо впихать их в запрос `WHERE ... AND id IN ({$ids})` все дальнейшие пхп проверки избыточны. надо из базы тащить только то что надо, а не все и потом фильтровать.